# TFS 2010 Build :On Hyper-V error: "The request was aborted: The operation has timed out. "

Tags: tfsbuild

I was able to run the tfs build successfully on our Windows Server 2008 R2 Machine. However, when we decided to move our TFS Build on Hyper-V running Windows Server 2008 R2, I'm getting this error.

[image]

```
 The request was aborted: The operation has timed out
```

Comment: Can you provide some more details?

Comment: look in the Event Viewer for error details. Maybe a network problem between sharepoint or reporting services or something

Comment: Please show where the errors are from in the log. This summary view only tells what the errrors are.

Comment: ok, i will post it. thank you for your prompt response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I saw the screenshot of your problem. This was exactly the same problem I encountered before and I also setup our build server in Hyper-V.

The pointers below might help you.

- [Increase Time-Out Time of your TFS Server](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ablock/archive/2008/09/16/increasing-the-time-out-time.aspx)

  - you could issue iis reset on your server or reboot the machine after changing the registry just to be sure that the tfs is restarted.
- Check your workspace configuration for the build definition so that only required files are downloaded during the build.
- [Configure the build project to use incremental build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833876.aspx).

I hope these would help you. The option 1 solved my problem... =)

Thank you!